# Title palettes provide small skipping below the title when it has two lines

Tags: beamer, titles

[image]

The palette above has low skip which looks ugly. How can we add a little padding like the one we get with one line titles?

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme[]{split}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}

\newlength{\widthTextMarginLeft}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginLeft}{1.5mm}
\newlength{\widthTextMarginRight}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginRight}{2mm}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=\widthTextMarginLeft, text margin right=\widthTextMarginRight}

\newlength{\sidebarWidth}
\setlength{\sidebarWidth}{0.3\paperwidth}

\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\sidebarWidth, sidebar width right=0cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Uncovering Contents When They Cannot Fit in One Slide}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" is that the last line of your first title "One Slide" does not contain any descending letters, while "Uncovering Contents" has the "g" as descending letter. If you want all titles to behave like the second case, you can add a `\strut` after `\insertframetitle` in the template definition:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme[]{split}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}

\newlength{\widthTextMarginLeft}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginLeft}{1.5mm}
\newlength{\widthTextMarginRight}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginRight}{2mm}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=\widthTextMarginLeft, text margin right=\widthTextMarginRight}

\newlength{\sidebarWidth}
\setlength{\sidebarWidth}{0.3\paperwidth}

\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\sidebarWidth, sidebar width right=0cm}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fteleft\endcsname\fi%
    \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\strut\insertframesubtitle\par}%
      \fi
    }%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Uncovering Contents When They Cannot Fit in One Slide}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: related bug report: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/535

Comment: @samcarter wants to add that 
this problem was fixed in the development version of beamer, see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/11adcd73e79cdf5400c69ff5c141a2e8c86710d0

Answer (score 0):

Running your code, I get the proper padding. However you can use `\vspace` at the end of the contents:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme[]{split}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}

\newlength{\widthTextMarginLeft}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginLeft}{1.5mm}
\newlength{\widthTextMarginRight}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginRight}{2mm}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=\widthTextMarginLeft, text margin right=\widthTextMarginRight}

\newlength{\sidebarWidth}
\setlength{\sidebarWidth}{0.3\paperwidth}

\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\sidebarWidth, sidebar width right=0cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Uncovering Contents When They Cannot Fit in One Slide\vspace{0.2cm}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```